# Can a table with a single row and a single column be used as a bool_expression?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have two tables like these:

```
    check_value1

    t

    check_value2

    f
```

Each table always has a single column and a single row containing a boolean value.

I want to use these tables in an if..then..else condition of plpgsql like this:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION if_logic()
    RETURNS void AS
    $$
    IF  check_value1 is true and check_value2 is true THEN  operation1
    ELIF check_value1 is false and check_value2 is false THEN operation2
    ELSE operation3      
    $$
    language plpgsql
```

How can this be done?

Comment: @operation is a very complex selection behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create function if_logic()
returns void as $$
begin
select case
    when cv1.check_value and cv2.check_value then operation1
    when not cv1.check_value and not cv2.check_value then operation2
    else operation3
    end
from check_value1 cv1 cross join check_value2 cv2
;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```